# Is the support of an Artinian module finite?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nonnoetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, $M$ is an Artinian $R$-module. Is the set $Supp_R(M)$ finite?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.

You can find a proof in Leamer's thesis [Homology of Artinian Modules Over Commutative Noetherian Rings](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1020&context=mathstudent&sei-redir=1#search=%22artinian%20module%20noetherian%20rings%22), which contains the the following more precise result (see Lemma 3.1.11):

> Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring and let $M$ be an artinian $R$-module. Then
>
> 1) the support of $M$ consists entirely of maximal ideals of $R$, that is, $\textrm{Supp}(M) \subseteq \textrm{m-Spec}(R)$;
>
> 2) we have $\textrm{Min}_R(M)=\textrm{Ass}_R(M)=\textrm{Supp}_R(M)$;
>
> 3) $\textrm{Supp}_R(M)$ is finite.

Comment: A more general statement is true: Suppose $A$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then there exists a finite increasing sequence $0=M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq\dotsb\subseteq M_n=M$ such that $M_i/M_{i-1}\cong A/P_i$ for some prime ideal $P_i$. Moreover, $\operatorname{Ass}(M)\subseteq\{P_1,\dotsc,P_n\}\subseteq\operatorname{Supp}(M)$, and three sets have the same minimal elements. (J-P.Serre, *Local Algebra*, section I.7)

Comment: Dear @user20948, please note that the result from Serre's book is NOT more general than Leamer's lemma. An artinian module over a noetherian ring may not be finitely generated.

Answer (score 6):

It is well-known that for finitely generated Artinian $M$, the support is a finite set of maximal ideals. Since $\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\bigcup_{M'\subseteq M\ \mathrm{f.g.}}\mathrm{Supp}(M')$, we know that $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ consists of maximal ideals. For any finite set $S\subseteq\mathrm{Supp}(M)$, it again follows easily from the finitely-generated case that $f_S\colon M\to\prod_{s\in S}M_s$ is surjective. In particular, for a strictly increasing chain $S_1\subset S_2\subset\dots$ of finite subsets of $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$, the chain of submodules $\ker(f_{S_i})$ is strictly decreasing, so $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ must be finite.